# Memory Leak on DeleteOnExitHook

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, akka

I have a Java application running 24/7, it has a connection to a MySQL server and a TimerTask (is running Akka). I'm running into OutOfMemoryError after a week or less of operation and the heap dump reveals a LinkedHashMap with over 4 millions of Strings, they have a GC root of java.io.DeleteOnExitHook using 800 MB of heap.

All the Strings are something like /tmp/jar_cachexxxx.tmp

This problem is consistent in two machines running OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13). The JDBC driver is the one provided on maven "mysql-connector-java" version 5.1.38 and I'm using the connection pool BoneCP, version 0.8.0.

Anyone has an idea about this leak?

**Update -- 5/12/16**

The problem has been solved after we've changed the compiler for the project. We noticed that eclipse jar creator was the only thing that has any relation with jar cache, so after we compiled the project with maven, the memory leak was gone.

Comment: Could you give more information how you're accessing the database and using Akka? Are you calling Java.io.File.deleteOnExit() ? How many strings did you look at that looked like "/tmp/jar_cachexxxx.tmp"? That might be a red herring. Even if there are 1000s of those strings doesn't account for 800MB. Try looking for other Strings.

Comment: How did you determine that _all_ the strings looked like "/tmp/jar_cachexxxx.tmp"? 800MB means that you would need about 800MB/30bytes=26,666,666  strings that look like that.

Answer (score 12):

This is a long-standing and well known bug that has been reported to Sun/Oracle MANY times over the years.  The current bug number is [JDK-4872014](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4872014).

The issue is that each time you use the delete-on-exit API the File gets stored into a `HashMap`.  Since in a long-running server your code rarely intentionally exits, the map can grow without bounds if you are doing this with lots of temporary files.

Essentially, the API is not usable with long-running servers because it's not really intended to be used that way.  If you need this functionality you need to implement it yourself and run the cleanup on a schedule, with some way to know which files can be deleted.

Comment: That shouldn't be the JVM's bug. The JVM needs to remember all the files that it needs to remove when the application exits. I'm surprised it's still an open issue.

Comment: You are probably right. That API is not intended for processes that ideally never shut down.

Answer (score 3):

It only happens when you use the eclipse exporter "Runnable JAR file" and then choose "Package required libraries into generated JAR".

Then the eclipse JAR-in-JAR classloader will be used, which uses an URLClassloader, which will produce a memory leak according to this question:
[How long are resources used (file descriptor and memory) for Java temporary files (jar_cache####.tmp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815714/how-long-are-resources-used-file-descriptor-and-memory-for-java-temporary-file)

Comment: Interesting, this solved my issue. I had a standalone service running that I create using these settings. Now I packed my dependencies in a seperate dir and no longer a memoryleak occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Something in your application is using File.deleteOnExit. But since your application never exists, Java has to keep track of all those files, because they need to be deleted when it finally exits (which never happens).
I suggest you find out which part of your application does this using the debugger and then find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a clue in the pathname of the files: "/tmp/jar_cachexxxx.tmp".

Apparently, those files are created when a URLClassloader downloads a remote JAR file and loads it.  If you have millions of these strings, that implies you are doing that far too often.